# Name the first item from a list that is not in another list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I am working with a list of articles in one spreadsheet `files` as the data source. The data is split into a source reference code in columns `A` to `E`, the title of the article in column `F` and the author in column `G`.

[image: The files Spreadsheet header & 1 example]

Now, I need to get the authors and the number of articles in the spreadsheet `analysis`. Column `A` is to hold the author names again and column `B` will contain the match `=Countif(files!G:G,A2)` to automatically count how often which one appears.

[image: the analysis header]

Now, here comes the problem: I can't manually type all the author's names into `analysis!A`! I thought, that maybe there is a function that could check if an author has been named above the current field in column A, and if not pull that name from `files!F`, but I fail at this task.

Is there a smart formula that can automatically fill it in?

**edit:**

With cybernetic.nomad's help, I could figure out that I have 236 different authors on the 419 titles.

Comment: "I can't manually type all the author's names..." You can copy them and remove duplicates. (Data -> Data Tools - Remove Duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, for extracting unique values using formulas currently you only have one option. It is an array formula (entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) like this one:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(files!$G$2:$G$10, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A1, files!$G$2:$G$10), 0)),"")
```

The range `files!$G$2:$G$10` cannot be an entire column, like `files!$G:$G`, because then array formulas actually run on entire column, which is badly slow. So choose your range wisely.

Comment: Then, please try this answer. It is designed to be put in cell `analysis!A2` and copied down.

Comment: It does not work at all. It returns empty string for all, which means it counts 1048155 empty cells in Column B

Comment: after having spent 2 hours trying to get it to work I think +part of the reason why your formula likely does not work is, that countif only allows a single item in the second argument to match the item against, match expects  a criterium what to look for in the first argument, a matrix in the second. Your formula does *neither*. Index can take the gole column in the first argument, and expects a number in the second argument.

Comment: Have you actually used Ctrl + Shift + Enter? So that at the end you have curly braces around your formula, like `{=IFERROR.....}` ? Manual typing the braces does not work, it must be the combination of keyboard keys.

Comment: using CTRL+SHIFT+RETURN does not result in changing that before input... you seem to have to use the command *post* input (which you forgot to mention), but with that it works apparently. Even with full column check.